# How to convert List<string> to xml document in c#

Tags: c#, xml, tstringlist

I would like to convert the List to a xml document in c#.

My code is as follows:

```
List<string> BugWSResponseList1 = new List<string>();
Logger.Write("\n\n" + DateTime.Now + " : " + " : START : Creation of a set of Bugs via bug.Add API");
BugWSResponseList1 = CreateBugs(FilePath_EXPRESS_API_BugAdd_CreateBugs_DataFile);
Logger.Write("\n\n" + DateTime.Now + " : " + " : END : Creation of a set of Bugs via bug.Add API");
```

I have been trying to convert the list response to string and then tried to convert it in xml document but when i parse it then it shows that there are more than one root elements in the xml.

The format of xml is as follows:

```
<Bug>
      <family>ESG</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <productarea>1</productarea>
      <subarea></subarea>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <duplicateId></duplicateId>
</Bug>
<Bug>
      <family>TEST22</family>
      <product>Dr.Watson</product>
      <version>Xpress API</version>
      <productarea>1</productarea>
      <subarea></subarea>
      <qe>sdawar</qe>
      <duplicateId></duplicateId>
</Bug>
```

Please note that it has two different  nodes in the xml.
What i am doing so far is converting List BugWSResponseList1 to a string and then loading it as xml.here is the code i am doing:

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
                    string s = string.Join(",", BugWSResponseList2);                    
                    xd.LoadXml(s);
```

But when i am doing it it says that there are more than one root element in the xml.

I would like to convert the List BugWSResponseList1 to an xml document as i need to parse it further for my code execution.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: [xmlwriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx), your question is unanswerable, how is it possible to know what format your strings are in? are they valid xml? does it need parsing?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your List too.

Comment: Message is clear: `there are more than one root element in the xml.` Your xml is invalid.

Comment: An xml must have *one and only one* root element (kinda like Highlander). In your case the xml should probably look something like `<Bugs><Bug>...</Bug><Bug>...</Bug></Bugs>` - Also, i *assume* that one entry in `BugWSResponseList2` looks like `"<Bug>...</Bug>"`. So joining them with `","` cannot result in a valid xml.

Comment: @Corak yess thats exactly what i am facing and looking for a solution. can i treat them as two different nodes in xml having same root element in both of the nodes present.

Comment: More and more I get the feeling that you did not fully understand, how xml works and how you should be working with it. For example, putting a node as a string into a list or your other question with replacing the value of a node. I urge you to read [Creating XML Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb387068.aspx), maybe even start with the [LINQ to XML Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb387087.aspx) and rethink your approach to the whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use XElement or XDocument and LINQ. Providing a sample of what the XML should look like we could provide more info.

For instance:

```
BugWSResponseList1.Add("<Bug><family>TEST22</family><product>Dr.Watson</product><version>Xpress API</version><productarea>1</productarea><subarea></subarea><qe>sdawar</qe><duplicateId></duplicateId></Bug>");

BugWSResponseList1.Add("<Bug><family>ESG</family><product>Dr.Watson</product><version>Xpress API</version><productarea>1</productarea><subarea></subarea><qe>sdawar</qe><duplicateId></duplicateId></Bug>");

XElement xe = new XElement
              (
                  "Bugs",
                  BugWSResponseList1
                  .Select 
                  (
                      x=>
                      XElement.Parse(x)
                  )
              );
```

So after i have loaded the list with the two pieces of xml you have provided i do the following:

I create a new XElement that will hold the root of the XML. I name that root as `Bugs`. Then as children of that root i put the contents of your List after parsing them into XElement objects.

The above code will result to :

```
<Bugs>
  <Bug>
    <family>TEST22</family>
    <product>Dr.Watson</product>
    <version>Xpress API</version>
    <productarea>1</productarea>
    <subarea></subarea>
    <qe>sdawar</qe>
    <duplicateId></duplicateId>
  </Bug>
  <Bug>
    <family>ESG</family>
    <product>Dr.Watson</product>
    <version>Xpress API</version>
    <productarea>1</productarea>
    <subarea></subarea>
    <qe>sdawar</qe>
    <duplicateId></duplicateId>
  </Bug>
</Bugs>
```

What you were missing was the root element. XmlDocument needs to have a root element defined.

In your case you could get away with it in you code by just adding  in the start of your joined string and  in the end, like the following, but i think my solution is more robust.

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
string s = "<Bugs>" + string.Join(",", BugWSResponseList2) + "</Bugs>";                    
xd.LoadXml(s);
```

Comment: Please find the sample xml i have added to my query above.Thanks.

Comment: We need to know what data you have in your List that will provide the expected result

Comment: I have two different nodes with <Bug> as root tag for each nodes in the list <string> response.I have specified the complete list response in the sample xml added above.

Comment: Thansk for the solution. It really goes me further. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all list entries and use the XMLSerializer class to create an xml document.
A very good explanation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813)

Comment: `list<string>{"a","b","c"}` - this wouldn't produce a valid xml file