# How can i pass List<string> response as an xml document using c#

Tags: c#, xml, string, list

I would like to pass an List response as an xml document and want to load it as xml.
Currently i am performing it using this code :

```
List<string> BugWSResponseList1 = new List<string>();
BugWSResponseList1 = CreateBugs(FilePath_EXPRESS_API_BugAdd_CreateBugs_DataFile, newValue);
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
//string s = string.Join(",", BugWSResponseList2);
//xd.LoadXml(s);                    
string s = "<Bugs>" + string.Join(",", BugWSResponseList1) + "</Bugs>";
xd.LoadXml(s);

//Dictionary Creation for Benchmark API                  
XmlDocument ResponseNode_bugs = null;
ResponseNode_bugs = new DrWatsonCore().LoadXMLDocument(s);
```

I would like to avoid to convert the `List<string>` response to string first and then loading it as xml.
Please suggest how can i achieve that.

Please find the detail of my `LoadXMLDocument` function as follows:

```
public XmlDocument LoadXMLDocument(string XMLData)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    try
    {
        doc.LoadXml(XMLData);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Write("\n\n" + DateTime.Now + " : " + "LoadXMLDocument : SEVERE ERROR : Failed to create XMLDocument from given string : \n\n");
        Logger.Write("\n\n" + DateTime.Now + " : " + "Exception : : \n\n" + ex.Message);
        Logger.Write("\n\n" + DateTime.Now + " : " + "Given String : : \n\n");

        if (DrWatsonHome.doVerboseLogging)
        {
            Logger.Write(XMLData);

        }
        else
        {
            string Response = XMLData;
            Logger.Write("\n\n" + DateTime.Now + " : " + "Response Length : " + Response.Length + " characters.");
            int ResponseLengthToPrint = DrWatsonHome.VerboseLogging_Length_Chars < Response.Length ? DrWatsonHome.VerboseLogging_Length_Chars : Response.Length;
            Logger.Write("\n\n" + DateTime.Now + " : " + "Response : " + Response.Substring(0, ResponseLengthToPrint) + " ...");
        }
    }
    finally
    {
    }

    return doc;
}
```

Can i achieve it after making some modifications in it.Please suggest.

I am using List now and my function is as follows:

```
List<XElement> Sairam(string FilePath, string Timestamp)
{
    List<XElement> WSResponse = new List<XElement>();

    XmlDocument XDoc = new DrWatsonCore().LoadXMLFromFile(FilePath);
    XmlNode BugListNode = XDoc.SelectSingleNode("/DrWatson/Bugs");
    List<Bug> BugList = new DrWatsonCore().GetBugList(BugListNode);
    List<Thread> BugFtecherThreadList = new List<Thread>();
    foreach (Bug bug in BugList)
    {
        bug.FoundInBuild = Timestamp;
        string URL = new DrWatsonCore().CreateWXURL(EXPRESS_API_METHOD.bug_add, bug, REST_EndPoint, AppGUID, new WatsonUser(Username_Watson, Password_Watson));
        string Response = string.Empty;
        object URLobj = (object) URL;
        Response = CreateBug(URLobj);
        // WSResponse.Add(Response);

    }

    return WSResponse;
}
```

I would like to get the WSResponse as the final response of teh program but i am unable to fetch it. Please suggest so how can i get the response of this program from this function.

Comment: [Oh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734230/how-to-convert-liststring-to-xml-document-in-c-sharp), [hi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714386/how-can-i-replace-the-xml-elements-with-new-elements-in-c-sharp) [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696435/replacing-some-elements-in-xml-sample-xml-provided). No need to create a new user every time. - So, reading up on [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb387087.aspx) is still not an option?

Comment: I tried doing it but didnt found a way.can you please suggest a way to acieve it.

Comment: Please refer to my updated code above in this thread.

Comment: Well, the first thing that seems wrong is that you store xml nodes in a `List<string>`. Where are those nodes created? Why not store them as what they are, [XElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx). If they are in the format that really represents what they are, you can work with them much easier. - Now, when your `BugWSResponseList1` would actually be a `List<XElement>` you could create the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) like this: `var xd = new XDocument(new XElement("Bugs", BugWSResponseList1));`

Comment: Why do you load the xml from string just so you could put the *string* into `LoadXMLDocument` where it is *again* loaded into an XmlDocument? - If you still refuse to work with appropriate datatypes then why not at least just call it like `ResponseNode_bugs = new DrWatsonCore().LoadXMLDocument("<Bugs>" + string.Join("", BugWSResponseList1) + "</Bugs>");`?

Comment: @Corak Please find my updated code part in this mail thread.